# How to apply security patches in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, security-patch

My current magento version is 2.3.5-p1.
I want to apply the last version of security patch for the same version 2.3.5 . Whether it can be 2.3.5- p2 or 2.3.5-p5 , anything.
How can i apply . Please can someone send me step by step guide. Dont send Mageplaza link, i have already refer that and did not understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of magento 2.3.5 is 2.3.5-p2.

To upgrade from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.3.5-p2, following the below steps:

1. Run command:
   `composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update && composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p2 --no-update`
2. Run command: `composer update`
3. Run commands to run upgrade database, compile DI, deploy static content: `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento bin/magento s:s:d -f`

That's all, you're done.

Comment: How did you find the latest is 2.3.5-p2?

Comment: You can find all released magento versions here:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/versions.html


Btw, I hope you can upgrade to 2.4 version ASSAP, at least 2.4.4 to make your site safe.

Comment: @TuVan You suggest that the OP should upgrade to 2.4.4, I want to know how safe it is to upgrade? Current github shows over `1000+` issues, most of which are related to Magento 2.x.  Last time I tried to upgrade `2.3.7 to `2.4x` it did not turn out well.  So much incompatible changes, and PHP 8.  For OP and me, please advise how you would go about doing a safe upgrade from `2.3x to 2.4x` without half of the things just imploding?

Comment: @CvRChameleon the github issues over 1000+ since some years ago til now...it does not mean 2.4.x is not good, and almost site was upgraded to 2.4.x. Magento 2.3 was end of support in September 8, 2022, so you only received security updates for 2.4.x (version <=2.4.3 will be end of support on November 28, 2022).

Comment: I would like to say that many site upgraded from 2.3 to 2.4 successfully and I've upgraded many sites which installed many 3rd-part extensions, customizations. The upgrade depends a lot on your site: 3rd-party extensions, customizations, but you able to upgrade from 2.3.x to 2.4.4 directly.

Comment: For a safe upgrade from 2.3x to 2.4.4, I would recommend do the upgrade on your local first and following these steps:
1. Upgrade system requirements: composer 2.1, PHP 8.1, Elasticsearch 7.16, Maria db 10.4, MySql 8.0,  RabbitMQ 3.9, Redis 6.2, Varnish 7.0.
2. Run command `composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update && composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4 --no-update`
3. Check the composer.json and make sure the `require-dev` section same as https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/composer.json#L113
4. Run command `composer update`

Comment: Step 5: Run commands to run upgrade database, compile DI, deploy static content: `bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento bin/magento s:s:d -f`.
There will be some issues if your 3rd-party extensions, your customizations do not compatible with PHP 8.1, so you have to fix it. After that, test the core journey on both storefront and admin, if you faced an issue, fix it. That's all. Hope it helps you, if you are stuck, feel free to let me know, I can help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will definitely do that on a clone on a local test server first (of course it would be a bad idea on production), as I mentioned last time I tried (start of this year) it didn't turn up encouraging results.  The PHP 8 incompatibilities is where I am mostly scared of (3rd party modules). I will give it a go.

Comment: I am sure this would also guide OP to try as well eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following commands from magento root

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update 
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p2 --no-update
composer update
```

Your magento security patch is applied after these